# Align text and reduce space between text and parentheses in plotly hover info box

Tags: r, plotly

I have this data

```
filtered_data<-structure(list(authorId = c("100508901", "100998451", "10159591", 
"102319456", "102648923", "103349940", "103471842", "103839825", 
"104207674", "10743363"), topicLabel = c("Societal Bias in AI", 
"Societal Bias in AI", "Societal Bias in AI", "Societal Bias in AI", 
"Societal Bias in AI", "Societal Bias in AI", "Societal Bias in AI", 
"Societal Bias in AI", "Societal Bias in AI", "Societal Bias in AI"
), authorTopicPaperCount = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), topicTotalInfluentialCitationCount = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), topicAvgInfluentialCitationCount = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), topicTotalCitationCount = c(5L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 8L, 0L), topicAvgCitationCount = c(5, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 0), marketShare = c(0.000902527075812274, 
0.000902527075812274, 0.000902527075812274, 0.000902527075812274, 
0.000902527075812274, 0.000902527075812274, 0.000902527075812274, 
0.000902527075812274, 0.000902527075812274, 0.000902527075812274
), authorName = c("R. Wolfe", "Martin Ferianc", "Quincy A. Hathaway", 
"Julie Jiang", "Charith S. Peris", "Bhavesh Neekhra", "J. Kshirsagar", 
"F. M. Zanzotto", "Z. Schillaci", "Utkarsh Agarwal"), authorSumOtherPapers = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0), plotlyTopicsAndCounts = structure(c("&nbsp;&nbsp; NA :  0", 
"&nbsp;&nbsp; NA :  0", "&nbsp;&nbsp; NA :  0", "&nbsp;&nbsp; NA :  0", 
"&nbsp;&nbsp; Federated LLM Optimization and Privacy :  1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Personality Trait Analysis in LLMs :  1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Privacy-Preserving Techniques in LLMs :  3", 
"&nbsp;&nbsp; NA :  0", "&nbsp;&nbsp; NA :  0", "&nbsp;&nbsp; Enhancing LLM Reasoning with CoT and Verification Methods :  1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Unassigned Papers :  2", 
"&nbsp;&nbsp; NA :  0", "&nbsp;&nbsp; NA :  0"), names = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Federated LLM Optimization and Privacy, Personality Trait Analysis in LLMs, Privacy-Preserving Techniques in LLMs", 
NA, NA, "Enhancing LLM Reasoning with CoT and Verification Methods, Unassigned Papers", 
NA, NA)), topicSpecializationScore = c("1.0000", "1.0000", "1.0000", 
"1.0000", "0.1667", "1.0000", "1.0000", "0.2500", "1.0000", "1.0000"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

and I create the plot below:

```
library(plotly)
# Create the Plotly graph without color based on total papers in other topics
plot <- plot_ly(data = filtered_data[1:10,], x = ~jitter(marketShare), y = ~topicAvgInfluentialCitationCount, 
                type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
                marker = list(size = ~log10(topicTotalCitationCount), sizemode = 'diameter', sizeref = 0.1,
                              color = ~topicSpecializationScore, colorscale = 'Bluered', 
                              colorbar = list(title = "Topic Specialization Score<br>")),
                hoverinfo = 'text',
                text = ~paste('<b>Name:</b>', authorName,
                              '<br><b>Publications (Current Topic):</b>', authorTopicPaperCount,
                              '<br><b>Market Share (Current Topic):</b>', marketShare, 
                              '<br><b>Topic Specialization Score:</b>', topicSpecializationScore,
                              '<br><b>Total Influential Citations (Current Topic):</b>', topicTotalInfluentialCitationCount, 
                              '<br><b>Average Citation Count (Current Topic):</b>', topicAvgCitationCount,
                              '<br><b>Author ID:</b>', authorId,
                              '<br><b>Number of Papers in Other Topics : (',authorSumOtherPapers,'):</b><br>',plotlyTopicsAndCounts))

# Customize layout with wrapped titles
plot <- plot %>% layout(
  xaxis = list(title = 'Market Share of Papers'),
  yaxis = list(title = 'Average Influential Citation Count'),
  margin = list(l = 70, r = 50, b = 90, t = 80),
  hoverlabel = list(align = "left")
)
# Render the plot
plot
```

As you can see in the image the first name of the list `"Enhancing LLM...."` is a little to the left from the rest of the names so I would like to align it with the rest of the names, also `"( 3 )"` should be `"(3)"` with not so much space between number and parentheses.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the extra whitespace you could remove the `&nbsp;` from your string and use `str_squish` to remove the unnecessary whitespaces. If you want to add some space you could add that to the `text` argument like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(stringr)

filtered_data$plotlyTopicsAndCounts <- gsub("&nbsp;", "", filtered_data$plotlyTopicsAndCounts)
# Create the Plotly graph without color based on total papers in other topics
plot <- plot_ly(data = filtered_data[1:10,], x = ~jitter(marketShare), y = ~topicAvgInfluentialCitationCount, 
                type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
                marker = list(size = ~log10(topicTotalCitationCount), sizemode = 'diameter', sizeref = 0.1,
                              color = ~topicSpecializationScore, colorscale = 'Bluered', 
                              colorbar = list(title = "Topic Specialization Score<br>")),
                hoverinfo = 'text',
                text = ~paste('<b>Name:</b>', authorName,
                              '<br><b>Publications (Current Topic):</b>', authorTopicPaperCount,
                              '<br><b>Market Share (Current Topic):</b>', marketShare, 
                              '<br><b>Topic Specialization Score:</b>', topicSpecializationScore,
                              '<br><b>Total Influential Citations (Current Topic):</b>', topicTotalInfluentialCitationCount, 
                              '<br><b>Average Citation Count (Current Topic):</b>', topicAvgCitationCount,
                              '<br><b>Author ID:</b>', authorId,
                              '<br><b>Number of Papers in Other Topics: (',authorSumOtherPapers,')</b><br>',str_squish(plotlyTopicsAndCounts)))

# Customize layout with wrapped titles
plot <- plot %>% layout(
  xaxis = list(title = 'Market Share of Papers'),
  yaxis = list(title = 'Average Influential Citation Count'),
  margin = list(l = 70, r = 50, b = 90, t = 80),
  hoverlabel = list(align = "left")
)
plot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @firmo23 `paste` will by default separate with a space. To fix that, wrap the problematic part of your string in `paste0`, i.e. something like `paste0("(", authorSumOtherPapers, ")")`.